# How to reserve port number and avoid other applicationsto use this specific port number?

Tags: linux, port, redhat-enterprise-linux, services

We have a Linux machine running RHEL version 7.9.
In this machine, we have installed the Ticktok service, which uses the port number `4590`.

Sometimes the service stops and doesn't use port number `4590`.

The problem is that when the service doesn't use the port, then other applications may use it, and when the service starts, then it fails because port `4590` is already in use.

So how can we reserve port number `4590` for Ticktok service?

Additional details:

1. port number can't be `1024`, we must use port number 4590
2. service is part of `systemctl` services
3. Ticktok service is sometimes down for maintenace purposes.

Comment: "We installed" -- Are you root then? Can you use a [privileged port](https://www.w3.org/Daemon/User/Installation/PrivilegedPorts.html)?

Comment: yes I am root and have the highest privilege

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add more details. You did not answer the question if you can use a privileged port (<1024) instead of 4590? Describe your network setup. Is a router involved that does port forwarding? Do you start the service on system startup? Or why is it not already started when some other application might get this port number?

Comment: see the update answer

Comment: "we must use port number - 4590" -- Because clients connect to this port exactly? Or because it's hardcoded in the server application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The article [How do I reserve ports for my application?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/15511/how-do-i-reserve-ports-for-my-application) has several possibilities.

One answer is that the following command will prevent the port from
being allocated, but will not stop a program from binding to it:

```
sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_local_reserved_ports = 4590.
```

Another answer is to change the range for the allocation of
dynamic ports to not include `4590` using `sysctl` for
`net.inet.ip.portrange.first` and `net.inet.ip.portrange.last`.

Comment: no so understand the "stop a program from binding to it:" , what in case we stop the service Ticktok , in that case I assume we not see the port is listening by netstat -tulpn , so what happened in that case? you mean in spite service is down then any application cant take the port number?

Comment: In almost all cases an application asks for a dynamic port without specifying the port, and the system allocates a random port from the dynamic pool, because most applications don't care which dynamic port they are assigned, and a random port is also a protection against hackers. The above setting will prevent port 4590 from being dynamically allocated by the system. However, an application like Ticktok that specifies the port by number as 4590, will still get it because this port is not in use.

Comment: ok , about what you sad "The above setting will prevent port 4590 from being dynamically allocated"  , once I configured sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_local_reserved_ports="4590"  , then how we can test that ? I mean how to verify that dynamically allocted not take this port?

Comment: for example I did sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_local_reserved_ports="4590"  , then I opened another session with  nc --listen --source-port 4590 , but its used this port , wo where I am wrong ? or what is the right test ?

Comment: if you want, I can post another Question thread about how to verify that port that reserved not be used by dynamically allocated by the system

Comment: For testing, you may set the random ports pool to a a very small range, something like 4590-4591 (backup the old values!) and run the other application that uses random dynamic ports and check if the port is used.

Comment: ok , but instead to run other application , is it possible to do simulation without to use the application? I mean like use the port as I did with nc  , because for now I can run the application but I want to verify that this setting is correct.

Comment: I think that `nc` is called with a specific port number, not a dynamic one. This setting doesn't protect against a program that wants specifically to open port number 4590 and no other. Any program that asks by number for 4590 will get it. However, the port will not be allocated for a program that asks for any random available port and doesn't care which one it gets.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/147833/discussion-between-king-david-and-harrymc).